# Design suggession on Spring component and multiple repositories

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have an API component class and each of its business methods need different repositories. This is what I have for example:

```
@Component
@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS,
                rollbackForClassName="java.lang.Throwable")
@EnableTransactionManagement 
public class TransactionApi
{
    @Autowired
    private TransactionRepository repo;
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository prodRepo;
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository custRepo;
    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepo;
    @Autowired
    private ContactRepository contactRepo;
    @Autowired
    private ShippingPrefsRepository shipPrefsRepo;

    @Transactional (readOnly=true)
    public Transaction getTransactionDetails(String transactionId)
    {
        return repo.findOne(transactionId);
    }

    @Transactional (readOnly=true)
    public Product getProductDetails(String productId)
    {
        return prodRepo.findOne(productId);
    }

    @Transactional (readOnly=true)
    public Customer getCustomerDetails(String customerId)
    {
        return custRepo.findOne(customerId);
    }

    public Order createOrder(Order order)
    {
        Order saved = orderRepo.save(order);
        return saved;
    }

    public Contact createContact(Contact contact)
    {
        Contact saved = contactRepo.save(contact);
        return saved;
    }

    public ShippingPreference createContact(ShippingPreference shipPref)
    {
        ShippingPreference saved = shipPrefsRepo.save(shipPref);
        return saved;
    }
```

Looking at above design, i have a lot of repositories used in one class and so not all are used each time this class is used. So i think initializing all of them upfront would be an overkill (I assume). I am worried that this might slow down my application or use lot of resources (memory). I will probably will have another 20 repositories when I am done with this class.

My question is am I designing it correctly as it should be done? Or is there better way of doing it. Loading too many repositories into memory when each time just one of those are being used, isn't it inefficient way of doing it? Any suggestions/advice are appreciated.

Comment: Your repositories are likely to get loaded when Spring loads, so there is not a lot of overhead of injecting into this class.  That is unless you use the @Lazy tag.  Which I would not necessarily recommend, because startup time is less important the runtime.  All that said, I would recommend breaking up this API into different sub-domains of our application.  Or a transaction API for each repository.

Comment: Over all i have about 250 repositories in my application and i am planning to group these into 15-20 API classes so each have about 10-15 repositories autowired. Are you suggesting have one API per repository?

Comment: Breaking it up to 15-20 APIs sounds like a good plan.  It's hard to say what the "right" way to do it is.  That comes down to personal preferences.